# Azure API Management list of methods

Tags: azure-api-management

I host a web API to Azure app service, and using Azure API management to manage the web API. However when I add a API app to the API management. the List of methods are empty.

[image]

If a add WADL, it will list all the methods.

[image]

Comment: What tech are you using for the WebAPI?  How are you generating the OpenApi document (Swagger)?  We try and create a name based on a combination of the OperationId, the Description, the path key, the method.  It just depends on what information is in the OpenAPI description.  I've not seen the situation you are showing before.  Can you show a sample of the OpenAPI description?